# Single-Spa: Uncaught Error: application 'app1' died in status UNMOUNTING: unmountComponentAtNode(...): Target container is not a DOM element

Tags: react-scripts, micro-frontend, react-16, single-spa

I have registered 4 react applications using registerApplication of Single Spa. When I am navigating from one app to another I am seeing an error in console as well as an overlay on the browser.

```
Uncaught Error: application 'app1' died in status UNMOUNTING: unmountComponentAtNode(...): Target container is not a DOM element.
```

This is how my index.js looks like from the registered micro-app:

```
function domElementGetter() {
  return document.getElementById('app1-placeholder');
}

const reactLifecycles = singleSpaReact({
  React,
  ReactDOM,
  rootComponent: App,
  domElementGetter,
  errorBoundary() {
    return <div>This renders when a catastrophic error occurs</div>;
  },
});

export const { bootstrap } = reactLifecycles;
export const { mount } = reactLifecycles;
export const { unmount } = reactLifecycles;
```

I am registering my application in single-spa-config file using SystemJS for import as below:

```
    registerApplication('app1', SystemJS.import('app1'), pathPrefix('app1'));
    
    function pathPrefix(prefix) {
      return (location) => location.href.indexOf(`${location.origin}/${prefix}`) !== -1;
    }
```

I don't know where to debug about this problem. Please help!

Comment: Did you find any solution to this ? I am getting same error.